# Attach Jprofiler to running app on Android Device

Tags: java, android, jprofiler

I need to profile an application developed for android platform. I've already used jprofiler in web-application development.  I use Android Studio (and Eclipse with ADT plugin) and actually i use DDMS to check cpu and heap memory comsuption.

Is it possible to connect Jprofiler to a running application on Android device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JProfiler is a tool for profiling applications running on the Java virtual machine. Even though Android uses the Java language, it runs on a different virtual machine, so you can't use any of the Java profilers such as JProfiler or YourKit to profile the applications.

Instead, you need to use the Google-provided tools such as DDMS.

Comment: There is a plugin for android studio

Answer (score 2):

For Android, DDMS is deprecated, instead use [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html).

Comment: When I wrote the question, Android Profile was not ready.  Now you are right :)