# JProfiler Socket Error Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, jprofiler

I am trying to profile my android application code using jprofiler,for the very first time, which I have installed and integrated but as I click `Run-> Profile` 'app'` the jprofiler opens up with an error message after failing to connect.

```
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8849. Please make sure that the remote address is correct
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach Jprofiler to running app on Android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743442/attach-jprofiler-to-running-app-on-android-device)

Comment: JProfiler does not support profiling Android applications.

Comment: but there is a plugin for it in by intelliJ

Comment: Yes, so what? IntelliJ IDEA supports development of non-Android Java applications, and that's what the plugin is for. And the plugin is not "by" IntelliJ, it was developed by the authors of JProfiler.

Comment: There is a plugin for android studio also